# Cannot increase Ubuntu partition with GParted. Maximum size

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Before I started this, I went into Windows 8 and reduced it's size to allow roughly 10GB of unallocated data. I want to increase Ubuntu 12.10's partition to fill that void.

I ran Ubuntu (Trial) from my CD as told to in multiple tutorials and ran GParted. Here's my GParted screen:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

But, when I try to right click and "Move/Resize Partition", it does not allow me to increase the partition size any more. It's "max size" is what it's at currently. How do I make it take over the unallocated space?

sda1 = System Reserved
sda2 = Windows 8
ext4 = Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Which partition are you trying to increase?
right-click on sda4 in the list and expand it first. it constrains the expansion of sda5, which is what I assume you are trying to expand unsuccessfully

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the partition that is in the way.

i.e You need to move `sda4` and `sda5` to the left before you have room to expand sda3. You can see this from the graphical layout at the top.

Edit:

It is possible that you cant move sda4 and sda5 since one is inside the other. Can you try the below steps

- Expand `sda4` to encompass the entire free space.
- Move `sda5` to the left end of this free space(from the right end)
- Shrink `sda4` to again be as large as `sda5`
- Resize your linux partition `sda3`

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that. Could you please walk me through it? :P

Comment: If you are not able to move sda4/sda5. You can try to resize sda4 -> move sda5 -> shrink sda4

Comment: Yeah... Um... I tried what you said in your edit. It gave me an error. http://i.imgur.com/ppqexNW.png?1

Comment: @Jack what is the error exactly? All I see is a `!` in front of `/dev/sda2` but otherwise I see nothing else that looks like an error

Comment: This is the error: http://pastie.org/6092377

Comment: can you please reply? I'm really wanting to increase this partition.

Comment: @Jack I am sorry I am at a loss.. the error message is frustratingly brief.. Have you tried it again but one step at a time? with some small changes maybe

Comment: It has an error when increasing the size of sda4: http://i.imgur.com/3VHQtZA.png?1

Comment: @Jack again very unclear, it isnt mounted is it?

Comment: It IS unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't work on the partition you are currently booted into. Work on the ubuntu partition in Windows, or get another program that you can boot from a CD.

Comment: "I ran Ubuntu (Trial) from my CD as told to in multiple tutorials and ran GParted. "